# web user control properties behavior

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a web user control that has a couple of server-side divs on it. I created a property to the visibility of one of the divs.

The problem is when I change that property on the designer the whole properties windows goes blank until I click on some other control on the page then back on the control.

Is there somethiing I missing in code to prevent the properties window going blank when I change the custom property because if I the standard visibility property for the entire control the properties windows is fine.

Also, is there a way for the designer to reflect the custom visibility property if I change it to DivDisplay = false?

And finally, is there a better way to do this?

[image]

Comment: seems like some user specific issue.